# Suppose $X,\tau$ and $Y,\tau '$ are contractible to $x_0$ and $y_0$ respectively. Prove that $X\times Y$ is contractible and simply connected.

Tags: general-topology

Here is what I got so far.

Assume that $X,\tau$ and $Y,\tau '$ are contractible to $x_0$ and $y_0$ respectively.

Since $X,\tau$ is contractible to $x_0$

$$id_X \sim f(x)=x_0 $$

meaning there exist a map $H:X\times [0,1] \to X$ such that

$$H(x,0)=id_X$$
$$H(x,1)=x_0$$

similarly, $Y,\tau'$ is contractible to $y_0$

$$id_Y \sim g(x)=y_0 $$

meaning there exist a map $H':Y\times [0,1] \to Y$ such that

$$H'(y,0)=id_Y$$
$$H'(y,1)=y_0$$

Since $X\times Y =\{(x,y): x\in X, y\in Y\}$ so $id_{X\times Y} = X\times Y = image(id_x) \times image(id_Y)$ and now I don't know where I'm going with these useless fact

Comment: Note that $H : X \times [0,1] \to X$, not $H: [0,1]^2 \to X$. Similarly for $H'$.

Comment: Also, the equality $id_{X\times Y} = X\times Y$ makes little sense.

Comment: Are you aware of the fact that a contractible space is simply connected? Then you only have to show that the product is contractible.

Comment: @PandaBear yes, I know that fact, but I'm not allowed to use that yet, even if I do, I still need to show the product space is contractible first.

Comment: @DianeVanderwaif Hint: Use $H$ and $H'$ to construct a map from $X\times Y \times [0,1] \to X\times Y$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With your $H$ and $H'$ define $H'': (X \times Y) \times [0,1] \rightarrow X \times Y$ by $H''((x,y), t) = (H(x,t), H'(y,t))$.

A map into the product $X \times Y$ is continuous iff its compositions with the two projections (onto $X$ and $Y$) are both continuous. And these compositions are just $H$ and $H'$ essentially, so continuous by assumption. This shows that $H''$ is continuous.

And $H''(x,y), 0) = (H(x,0), H'(y,0)) = (x,y)$ for all $(x,y) \in X \times Y$, and also $H''((x,y), 1) = (H(x,1), H'(y,1)) = (x_0, y_0)$ as well. So this defines a contraction of $X \times Y$ to the point $(x_0, y_0)$.

And contractible spaces are simply connected. If you're not allowed to use that, you can use a modification of the above argument to show that a closed loop (w.r.t. a basepoint $(p, q)$) in $X \times Y$ is also homotopic to the constant map to that base point.

Comment: isn't it should be $H''((x,y),t)=(H(x,t),H'(y,t))$?

Comment: You're right, that's what I *thought* I wrote...

Answer (score 0):

Alternative proof requiring familiarity with categories.

The categories $\mathbf{Top}$ and $\mathbf{hTop}$ both have topological
spaces as objects and a topological space is contractible as object
of $\mathbf{Top}$ if and only if it is terminal as object of $\mathbf{hTop}$.

Secondly quotientfunctor $\left[\right]:\mathbf{Top}\rightarrow\mathbf{hTop}$
preserves products.

Thirdly the product of terminal objects is a terminal object.

Now the (short and elegant) proof:

$X,Y$ contractible in $\mathbf{Top}$ $\Rightarrow$ $X,Y$ terminal
in $\mathbf{hTop}$ $\Rightarrow$ $X\times Y$ terminal in $\mathbf{hTop}$
$\Rightarrow$ $X\times Y$ contractible in $\mathbf{Top}$.

It is not unthinkable that this is not (yet) of much use to you. However, see it as an encouragement to explore categories. It can be very enlightening.